# Error loading "npm:babel-core@5.5.6/browser.js"

Tags: npm, node-modules, babeljs, jspm, babel-core

I have installed npm and jspm packages but I get the following error in my browser when i try running my code.

**Error loading "npm:babel-core@5.5.6/browser.js" at 
http://localhost:9000/jspm_packages/npm/babel-core@5.5.6/browser.js.js
Error loading "npm:babel-core@5.5.6/browser.js" from "npm:babel-core@5.5.6" at http://localhost:9000/jspm_packages/npm/babel-core@5.5.6.js
Not Found: http://localhost:9000/jspm_packages/npm/babel-core@5.5.6/browser.js.js (WARNING: non-Error used)**

The npm folder has the browser.js file but i still get the above error. Below is a snapshot of my jspm-package folder structure and package.json file with the devDepencies

[jspm-package folder](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1dX1p.png)

package.json

```
"devDependencies": {
"almond": "^0.3.2",
"babel-core": "^5.8.38",
"chai": "^2.2.0",
"check-build": "^1.5.0",
"grunt": "^0.4.5",
"grunt-contrib-clean": "^0.6.0",
"grunt-contrib-copy": "^0.8.0",
"grunt-contrib-jshint": "~0.10.0",
"grunt-contrib-requirejs": "~0.4.4",
"grunt-serve": "^0.1.6",
"jsdoc": "^3.3.0-beta3",
"jspm": "^0.15.3",
"karma": "^0.12.31",
"karma-babel-preprocessor": "^5.1.0",
"karma-chai": "^0.1.0",
"karma-chrome-launcher": "^0.1.8",
"karma-cli": "0.0.4",
"karma-coverage": "^0.3.1",
"karma-jspm": "^1.1.4",
"karma-mocha": "^0.1.10",
"karma-mocha-reporter": "^1.0.2",
"karma-sinon": "^1.0.4",
"load-grunt-config": "^0.7.2" },

"jscsConfig": {
"esnext": true},
"jspm": {
"directories": {
  "test": "test"
},
"devDependencies": {
  "babel": "npm:babel-core@^5.1.13",
  "babel-runtime": "npm:babel-runtime@^5.1.13",
  "core-js": "npm:core-js@^0.9.4"
}
```

I have tried uninstalling npm and installing it again, but it doesn't seem to work. Please help me in resolving this. Thanks in advance.

The config file looks like:

```
System.config({
  "baseURL": "/",
  "transpiler": "babel",
  "babelOptions": {
   "optional": [
   "runtime"
    ]
  },
  "paths": {
    "github:*": "jspm_packages/github/*.js",
    "npm:*": "jspm_packages/npm/*.js",
    "*": "*.js"
   },
  "defaultJSExtensions": true
   });

System.config({
  "map": {
    "babel": "npm:babel-core@5.5.6",
    "babel-runtime": "npm:babel-runtime@5.5.6",
    "core-js": "npm:core-js@0.9.15",
    "github:jspm/nodelibs-process@0.1.1": {
      "process": "npm:process@0.10.1"
     },
    "npm:babel-runtime@5.5.6": {
    "process": "github:jspm/nodelibs-process@0.1.1"
     },
    "npm:core-js@0.9.15": {
      "fs": "github:jspm/nodelibs-fs@0.1.2",
      "process": "github:jspm/nodelibs-process@0.1.1",
      "systemjs-json": "github:systemjs/plugin-json@0.1.0"
      }
  }
});
```

Comment: Provide systemjs config please.

Comment: Hi Pavel, I have added the config file in my question. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I think, the problem is there:

```
"defaultJSExtensions": true
```

It is deprecated setting, and docs recomends to specify such behaviour [for every package separately](https://github.com/systemjs/systemjs/blob/master/docs/config-api.md#packages).

The reason is that someone writes `import "moduleName"`, and someone `import "moduleName.js"`. The setting fixes first case, by always adding `.js` to the end of the module. As you can see from error message, systemjs is trying to load `browser.js.js`, so you should specify for `babel` package option `defaultExtension: false` to prevent `.js.js` problem.

Comment: I still get the same error after having changed defaultExtension to 'false' in config.js file. Do i have to re-run any of the installations like npm and jspm again after I have changed the config.js file?